# CAGradientLayer is not working on iOS 7 (But working on iOS 6)

Tags: ios, calayer, ios7

I am using the code below to add a subtile gradient effect to my table cell.

```
    // add a layer that overlays the cell adding a subtle gradient effect
    CAGradientLayer* gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.bounds));
    gradientLayer.frame = cell.bounds;
    gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f] CGColor],
                             (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f] CGColor],
                             (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
                             (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.1f] CGColor]];
    gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.00f, @0.01f, @0.95f, @1.00f];
    [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

After the code ran, I can see the CAGradientLayer have been added to my cell.layer. But I can't see it at all when I run the app on my iOS 7 Simulator.

```
<CALayer:0xaca1980; sublayers = (<CAGradientLayer: 0xaad2110>, <CALayer: 0xaca2a70>);
```

The code works on iOS 6 without any problem.

If CAGradientLayer doesn't work on iOS 7 any more, what can I do to add gradients to my table cell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by changing

```
[cell.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

to

```
[cell.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:1];
```

For backward compatibility. I am using the code like this

```
    if ([Common isiOS7]) {
        [self.layer insertSublayer:_gradientLayer atIndex:1];
    }
    else {
        [self.layer insertSublayer:_gradientLayer atIndex:0];
    }
```

Comment: Any idea why? Working for me, but I don't "get" it. :)

Comment: None of this worked for me.  When I used the proposed solution my ui elements in the cell, an image and label, do not show, they are hidden under the gradient.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by setting the cell background color to clear.
In this case you could maintain the index as 0, so the elements are shown, and the gradient is shown too.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearcolor];
[cell.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment above, it is a bit foggy to me why this works. It seems that after a few tests on iOS6 I have 2 sublayers, where for iOS7 I have 1. What this has to do with the insertion of indexes is beyond me. I don't see why placing the gradient at index 1 works...doh! :)

But for my needs I required the gradient to appear above everything else, so instead of using the answer above with OS checks (which works perfectly fine BTW!!), i did something like:

```
[self.layer insertSublayer:_gradientLayer above:[self.layer.sublayers firstObject]];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** April, 2016

So I stumbled upon this question as I was experiencing a similar problem. For me the following miraculously did the trick:

instead of using `gradient.colors = @[*colors*]`, 
I had to use `gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: *colors*, nil]`

Could be an Apple bug, or something that I don't understand. Hope this helps anybody!